# SwiftUI The truncate behavior of the text with a link property and a /n is strange

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-text

I want to implement text that can detect links and click.

Everything was perfect, but I found one strange thing. When the Text with linelimit() and long string and the latter part is omitted, if there is a newLine before that, ellipsis disappears.

Without newLine, it works fine.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let text: String = "test test  www.google.com \n ddfk \n jdkfjdfd \n"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(linkDetectableText(text: text))
            .truncationMode(.tail)
            .lineLimit(2)
            .environment(\.openURL, OpenURLAction { url in
                print(url)
                return .handled
            })
            .onTapGesture {
                print("Tapped")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    func linkDetectableText(text: String) -> AttributedString {
        
        let mutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
        
        let normalText = NSAttributedString(string: text)
        mutableString.append(normalText)
        
        var urlAttributes: [NSMutableAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.blue,
            .underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue
        ]
        
        do {
            let detector = try NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
            let matches = detector.matches(
                in: text,
                options: [],
                range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.count)
            )
            for m in matches {
                if let url = m.url {
                    urlAttributes[.attachment] = url
                    mutableString.setAttributes(urlAttributes, range: m.range)
                    
                    //If you remove this code, the ellipsis appears normally, but url is not clicked.
                    mutableString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.link, value: url, range: m.range)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        
        return AttributedString(mutableString)
    }
}
```

[Result of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5U5D2.png)

[As a result of removing url attr from the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWYpi.png)

[The result of removing newLine from text in the code above and writing it long](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h8sB.png)

I tried adding a linebreak of paragraphStyle to the NSAttributedString, and I also tried the AttributedString instead of the NSAttachedString.
I tried using AttributedString only on the link Text by dividing the Text also did not work.

This strage behavior occurred when the link attribute added to AttributedString.
Is this a bug? Is there any way in SwiftUI that can fix this?